# Retorno da função system(); c++

Tags: c++

Alguém poderia me ajudar, já faz um tempo que estou com essa duvida, referente a como passar para um variável o retorno da função System();
Função essa que executa um determinado comando no console, e traz na tela os resultados.
Se eu por exemplo quisesse guardar em uma variável tipo string, a seguinte saída:

```
string hostname = system("whoami");
```

E fazer que com o conteúdo nela contido seja o `hostname` da maquina.

Comment: O retorno da função system é um int com valor 0 se correu tudo bem (depende da implementação) ou um valor diferente de zero caso o parâmetro seja NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez o que você precisa é da função `fopen` ao invés de `system`. Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
FILE* output_file = nullptr;
char buffer[1024];

output_file = popen("whoami", "r");

if(output_file)
{
    int i = 0;
    char c;

    while((c = fgetc(output_file)) != EOF)
    {
        buffer[i] = c;
        i++;
    } 
    buffer[i] = '\0';

    std::cout << buffer << '\n';
}
```

A função popen grava a saida do comando num arquivo, e este arquivo é retornado pela função. Daí é so salvar o conteúdo do arquivo no buffer.

Comment: Otimo, é exatamente o que eu preciso, poderia me explicar mais sobre o nullptr, pois em meu codigo diz que ele não foi declarado

Comment: nullptr é o mesmo que NULL, foi introduzido em c++11.  Nota que ao contrário de NULL, nullptr não é uma macro, é uma palavra reservada e eu recomendo que você o use. O erro  deve ser porque c++11 não está ativado. Vai logo e ativa, c++ moderno é bem melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Só para clarificar um pouco sobre a função `system`, pois a utilização que mostrou  não está correta:

```
string hostname = system("whoami");
```

A função `system` executa um determinado comando mas não devolve os resultados mostrados na tela e sim um inteiro. Passo a citar a [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) sobre o significado desse inteiro retornado:

> If command is a null pointer, the function returns a non-zero value in case a command processor is available and a zero value if it is not.
>
> If command is not a null pointer, the value returned depends on the system and library implementations, but it is generally expected to be the status code returned by the called command, if supported.

Em tradução livre:

> Se o comando for um ponteiro NULL, a função devolve um valor diferente de zero se o processador de comandos estiver disponível e zero caso contrário.
>
> Se o comando não for um ponteiro NULL, o valor retornado vai depender do sistema operacional e respetiva implementação, mas regra geral é esperado que seja um código de estado devolvido pelo comando executado, se suportado.

Em conclusão, o valor devolvido é um numero, que depende da implementação, mas regra geral é um código. Por isso esta função não devolve o que espera, embora o resultado da execução do comando seja visível na consola após chamar a função `system`.

Para obter o resultado da execução do comando como texto e guardar numa variável pode fazer como está na [resposta do @user72726](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/384199/82711)