# Detectar e mudar a mensagem de erro do System()

Tags: c, c++

Eu tenho uma dúvida acerca do uso da função `system`. Por exemplo, se executarmos o seguinte comando:

> system("exemplo");

Se o comando exemplo não for encontrado no sistema a função imprime a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> 'exemplo' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um
>   programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Como eu faço para trocar essa mensagem de erro que retorna para uma mensagem personalizada?

Comment: Talvez tenha uma forma bonita e direta de o fazer que eu desconheça, mas no minimo consegue fazer utilizando `popen` para executar o comando e guardar o resultado numa string, e comparando o resultado com esse texto de erro. Em windows se o resultado começar em `'comando'` então é sinal que não existe. Tem um exemplo de captura do resultado de execução de um comando na consola [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/384167/retorno-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-system-c/384253#384253)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Até onde sei**, isso não é possível de maneira oficial. Essa **mensagem** é **do shell do Windows**/**DOS** para quando você fornece um comando que não existe no sistema. E como o Windows é um **sistema fechado**, *provavelmente* este é um nome padrão imutável, não possuindo arquivo de configuração ou entrada no Registro do Windows.

Existem algumas possíveis **soluções**, tanto **realistas** como **não realistas**. Uma *solução realista* seria por meio de redirecionamento da mensagem de erro. Uma *solução não realista* seria por meio da engenharia reversa do shell do Windows para que se altere as mensagens. Este último caso é algo que foge da minha alçada e que é ilegal se não tiver autorização da Microsoft.

Vou tratar da solução realista em Windows e em Linux.

### Linux

Quando for invocar algum comando no shell por meio de `system`, você deve inicialmente redirecionar a mensagem de erro para o "[limbo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispositivo_nulo)" (`/dev/null`) com `2>`. O operador `2>` redireciona mensagens de erro do shell para algum lugar definido por você - neste caso, o limbo.

O exemplo a seguir tentar usar o comando de listagem de diretórios `ls`:

```
int cod_erro;
cod_erro = system("ls 2> /dev/null");
```

Em seguida, checa-se se o comando foi **INcorretamente executado**. Se for INcorretamente executado,`system` retornará o código de erro **`32512`** (ou `0x7F00` em *hexadecimal*).

```
if( cod_erro == 32512 ) printf("Minha frase!\n");
```

Se o comando for inválido, a mensagem será impressa. Caso contrário, o programa segue corretamente sem mensagem alguma de erro de invocação. Pode sim mostrar erros do programa em si sendo executado por meio de `system` mas isso foge do escopo da pergunta.

### Windows

Siga os mesmos passos seguidos para um sistema Linux - com algumas diferenças. No Windows, o limbo é `NUL`. Assim, usando o comando `DIR` de listagem de arquivos como exemplo, temos:

```
int cod_erro;
cod_erro = system("DIR 2> NUL");
```

O que pode mudar é o código de erro. Como não trabalho com Windows e observei falta de documentação (*em relação ao caso específico desta pergunta*), ensinarei a achar o código de erro.

Rode o seguinte **programa para achar o código de erro** no seu Windows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    printf("Cod: %d\n", system("DIRa"));

    system("PAUSE"); /* Para Windows. Substituir pelo equivalente em outro S.O. */
    return(0);

    }
```

Como o comando `DIRa` não existe, um código de erro será gerado. Use este código para colocar no condicional `if`. E pronto!

### Outros sistemas

Mudando pouca coisa ou mesmo nenhuma, é possível fazer o mesmo em outros sistemas. É necessário apenas saber:

- como redirecionar mensagens de erro no shell do sistema sendo usado;
- qual é o diretório do limbo do sistema;
- qual é o código de erro se o programa não existir;

Tendo estas informações, basta substituir o que for necessário no código exemplificado para Windows ou Linux. Não tem segredo.

---

* Se estiver errado, me corrijam!

Comment: Em vez de 32512 o correto não seria 0?? A função sytem retorna um valor diferente de zero só se o comando existe.

Comment: @user72726 Não. Só é retornado `0` quando se faz `system(NULL)` e não há um shell ou quando, obtendo sucesso na execução de um comando qualquer, este comando retorne `0` que por sua vez é repassado para `system` retornar ao seu código. Por exemplo, um `system("ls")` retorna `0`. Veja mais no manual (digite `man system` no terminal do seu pingüim) na seção de *Valor de Retorno* (ou *Return Value*). Alternativamente, faça uns testes com o código pra achar código de erro localizado na resposta. Talvez você precise modificar c/ uma GUI para conseguir observar certos comportamentos.

Comment: Sim tens razão. Eu que não tinha entendido o texto do cppreference